# xmodmap equivalent in bash

Tags: ssh, bash, keyboard-layout

I'm constantly on bash via ssh, on a computer that doesn't have X. In my computer I've switched the keyboards' <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys with `xmodmap`.

Is it possible to do it on the computer in which I log in? It's running Debian Lenny.

#### UPDATE

Is there an equivalent for **xev** too? I tried doing:

```
$ loadkeys ~/.loadkeys
```

where `~/.loadkeys` contained:

```
keycode 133=0xffe9
keycode  64=0xffeb
```

But it seems that `loadkeys` doesn't accept hexadecimal literals, since it fails with the message:

```
Couldnt get a file descriptor referring to the console
KDGKBMODE: Bad file descriptor
loadkeys: error reading keyboard mode
```

I also tried:

```
keycode 133=64
keycode 64=133
```

In which format should the new mapped key value (value in the right) be?

Comment: Bash is a shell.  You should be looking at changing your terminal emulator.  Are you connecting via putty, the local console, or something else?

Comment: @Zoredache, I use gnome-terminal.

Comment: Are you using Gnome-terminal or the Linux console then? Your comment and your question are contradictory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console equivalent is `loadkeys`. The key codes can be found with `showkey`. See: [The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mircea, I read the loadmap manual but I can't find the proper way to find the syntax and new key value format, so I edited the question.